# iOS, LiveQuery - Subscribe to a range of events at once?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, livequery

I'm trying out the LiveQuery SDK and I want to know, if it's possible to subscribe to create and update events, in one subscription...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! That's how you subscribe to all events:

`subscription = liveQueryClient.subscribe(chatRoomQuery)
 _ = subscription?.handleEvent { query, event in
     print(query)
     print(event)
}`